# Add filter 'wpautop' to meta box textarea

Tags: metabox, wp-autop

I'm using -[this tutorial](http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/)- to add simple meta boxes to a custom post type. But the textarea meta boxes are spitting out content all as one big paragraph, with no `<p>` formatting applied.

What code would add the -[wpautop filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)- to the meta box textarea? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a function that grabs your meta data, applies wpautop and echoes it out, or otherwise run it through when you output it in your template.

```
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
echo $my_meta['name'];
echo wpautop( $my_meta['description'], 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good Plugin for this Problem: http://www.bake-the-web.de/2012/03/22/no-wpautop/

It disables wpautop for Excerpt, Content or both.